# 2 inputfields same value dynamicly in 1 form

Tags: php, forms

I've 2 input fields which I want to have the same value.
When input field `id="name_1"` is filled in, I want to have it copied into input field `id="name_2"`.

How, or is this possible?

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name_1" id="name_1" value="">
    <input type="text" name="name_2" id="name_2" value="">
</form>
```

Comment: It is possible, with JS / jQuery.

Comment: PHP is server side. It will never do anything client side/on the browser. If you just want PHP to have `$_POST['name_2']` to have input `name_1`'s value you could just do `$_POST['name_2'] = $_POST['name_1'];`.

Comment: Ideally they'd both need to have different names, or else there's no way to differentiate one field from another in JS/Jquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do expected functionality using `Jquery` or `Javascript`. To make below operation work properly, you have to include [latest jQuery](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js) in your `html` page

Try this

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name_1" id="name_1" value="">
    <input type="text" name="name_2" id="name_2" value="">
</form>

<script>
    $("#name_1").keyup(function () {
      var value = $(this).val();
      $("#name_2").val(value);
    }).keyup();
</script>
```

[JS-FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/8nLv3krm/1/)

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#field1').blur(function(){
    $('#field2').val($(this).val());
});
});
</script>

<input type="text" name="field1" id="field1">
<input type="text" name="field2" id="field2">
```

Answer (score 1):

## HTML:

```
<input id="name1" class="name" type="text" /><input id="name2" class="name" type="text" />
```

## jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".name").keyup(function(){
        var val = $(this).val();
        $(".name").each(function(){
            $(this).val(val);
        });
    });
});
```

## JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/yzmdu308/

This way, if the 1st one gets changed, it changes the value of name2, and if name2 gets changed, it changes the value of name1.

Answer (score 1):

### Without using Angular JS

It is better to use class selector to update bind to two input text box elements.

**HTML**

```
<input id="name1" class="name" type="text" />
```

**JS**

```
$(".name").keyup(function(){
$(".name").val($(this).val()); });
```

**JS FIDDLE**

[Two way binding without Angular](https://jsfiddle.net/0dg8nokL/)

### With Angular JS

Angular providing very simple and efficient two way binding options. Please check the below sample.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app>
<input id="name1" ng-model="name" type="text" />
<input id="name2" ng-model="name" type="text" />
```

**JS FIDDLE**

[Two way binding with Angular](https://jsfiddle.net/vfm9tj2x/)